# MatrixInstruction does not function in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I would like to apply transformation matrix to a widget. In this case, I expect it to move 100 to right.

However, it does not move at all, but

```
Transformation:
    x: 100
```

worked well.

I have simplified the problem, I would actually like to apply some matrices from [here](https://www.gatevidyalay.com/3d-rotation-in-computer-graphics-definition-examples/). Besides, I have tested some matrices from there, it worked differently or just didn't show anything.

```
from kivy.graphics.transformation import Matrix
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.app import App

Builder.load_string("""
<MainScreen>:
    anchor_x: "center"
    anchor_y: "center"
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Button:
        id: widg
        size_hint: (0.3, 0.6)
        canvas.before:
            PushMatrix
            # Translate:
            #     x: 100
            MatrixInstruction:
                matrix: root.matrix
        canvas.after:
            PopMatrix
        text: "hello"
""")


class MainScreen(AnchorLayout):
    matrix = Matrix()
    matrix.set(array=[[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 100.0],
                      [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                      [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
                      [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print(self.ids.widg.canvas.before.children[1].matrix)


class Application(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Application, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Application().run()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your matrix is incorrect. Try:

```
matrix.set(array=[[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
              [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
              [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
              [100.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])
```

Comment: Oh, I see! I should type the columns in rows, thanks <3.

Comment: However, translation in z-axis (and also other tranformation regarding to change in z-axis) does not work?!

Comment: The best way to handle the matrices is to use the methods in [kivy.graphics.transformation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.graphics.transformation.html#module-kivy.graphics.transformation).